# Reverse Search for Character in String in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to search for the first location of a specific character in a string, starting from the end and proceeding to the beginning of the string.

I thought in Oracle you could use "instr" with a negative position parameter and it would start from the end of the string.

Snowflake doesn't have "instr", only "position" and that doesn't seem to allow searching from the end of the string.

Apart from reversing the string and using "position", is there another way to do this?

Comment: How about some regular expressions? Use REGEXP_COUNT to count how many times the character appears in the string. Then provide the result of the count as the occurrence parameter in REGEXP_INSTR. Something like this ```select regexp_instr('abcdeabcdeab', 'a', 1, regexp_count('abcdeabcdeab', 'a'));```

Answer (score 4):

There is the `regexp_instr()` function that would be helpful here:

```
SELECT regexp_instr('find the last t character','[t][^t]*$') as t

>23
```

That regex says to look for the following pattern: the literal letter "t" (`[t]`) occurring once followed by one or more characters that are NOT "t" (`[^t]`) until you hit the end of the string (`*$`).

Answer (score 3):

expounding on JNevil's answer:

```
SELECT 
    column1 as str
    ,regexp_instr(str,'[t][^t]*$') as pos
    ,substr(str, pos+1) as tail
    ,NVL(NULLIFZERO(position('t',reverse(str))),length(str)+1) as rev_pos_fixed
    ,right(str, rev_pos_fixed-1) as tail_2
FROM VALUES
  ('find the last t character'),
  ('none in here'),
  ('very last'),
  ('the only is beginning')
;
```

gives:

| STR | POS | TAIL | REV_POS_FIXED | TAIL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| find the last t character | 23 | er | 3 | er |
| none in here | 0 | none in here | 13 | none in here |
| very last | 9 |  | 1 |  |
| the only is beginning | 1 | he only is beginning | 21 | he only is beginning |

You can get POSITION/REVERSE answers to work with some edge case math, and RIGHT. Or just using REGEXP_INSTR

Answer (score 1):

A bit convoluted but you could:

- REVERSE the string
- Find the POSITION of the character
- Subtract the position from the length of the string

If this is something you want to do often then it would make sense to wrap it up in in a UDF

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake lacks LASTINDEXOF so you should write a basic UDF. This one is in Java.

```
public class LastIndexOfUdf implements JavaUDF2<String, String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer call(String character, String str) {
      if (str == null || character == null) return null;
      int idx = str.lastIndexOf(character);
      return (idx >= 0) ? idx + 1 : null;
    }
}
```