# Need the last character of Variant column in Snowfla

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
"<FONT STYLE='COLOR: #FOO'>
<！--12/15/73 05:51:25 pm-->
<B>12/15/73 10:51:25 am</B>
- <I>Tommy (0011) {Main}</I>
< FONT>
<BR>Started review in 1973"
```

Guys, Above is the Variant column value in Snowflake, any idea how to get the output as "Started review in 1973"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is simgle string you want get the last part.
Or if it's column it follows same pattern.
In that case you can use below query to get the required result.
It simply splits your column on 
 and return the last part

```
select split_part(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('
            <FONT STYLE='' COLOR:#F00''> <！--09/20/22 01:24:11 pm--> <B>20/09/22 06:24:11 am</B> - <I›System Admin (Main) (Main]</I> </FONT><BR><font style=''COLOR: #F00''><b>24/07/2022 10:13:44 am</b> - <i›Salman Khan (Main) (Main)</i›</font> <br>movie is great<br><br>':: variant
            ,'<br>|<BR>','')
            ,'font','FONT')

,'FONT>',-1) col_name;
```

Comment: Thank you, its working fine, but for below value, its not working,   "<FONT STYLE=' COLOR:#F00'>
<！--09/20/22 01:24:11 pm-->
<B>20/09/22 06:24:11 am</B> - <I›System Admin (Main) (Main]</I>
</FONT><BR><font style='COLOR: #F00'><b>24/07/2022 10:13:44 am</b> - <i›Salman Khan (Main) (Main)</i›</font> <br>movie is great<br><br>"

Comment: Check the updated query, I tried to make it more generic based on my understanding

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113951/reverse-search-for-character-in-string-in-snowflake